# Choosing $m$ such that $x^p + mp^2 \left(x^{p-2} + \sum_1^{p-2} (-1)^i e_i x^{p-2-i} \right) -p$ has exactly $p-2$ real roots

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I want to show it is possible to choose $m$ such that $x^p + mp^2 \left(x^{p-2} + \sum_1^{p-2} (-1)^i e_i x^{p-2-i} \right) -p$ has exactly $p-2$ real roots, where $e_i$ are positive constants. (So we really just care that all $e_i > 0$) It should be noted that $p$ is prime.

My approach has been via [Sturm's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem), but this is extremely painful as it involves calculating many derivatives and carrying out lots of polynomial division.

My question is whether there exists a more elegant approach to this calculation or an observation that I have missed.

Comment: $e_i$ are symmetric polynomials... in what? does it matter?

Comment: I've edited my post. They did not matter, just the fact that they are positive.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: That would provide an upper bound, how can I bound below and squeeze?

Comment: Apologies Exodd, my comment on upper bound was extremely stupid, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we expand the polynomial we can see the coefficients on $x^k$ are positive for $k$ odd and negative for $k$ even.

Using Descarte's rule of signs we see the sequence:
$$+,\underbrace{+,-,+,-,\dots}_{p-2 \text{ times}}$$
So we know the number of positive roots are at most $p-2$. Using the transform $x \to -x$ yields that there are no negative roots. Thus by Fundamental Theorem of Algebra we must have at least two complex roots. We can conclude with the method demonstrated in this answer: [Existence of irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Q$, which has exactly two non-real roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989296/existence-of-irreducible-polynomial-over-mathbb-q-which-has-exactly-two-non/989316#989316) (Using Rouche's Theorem)